# Why does the end user have to log out twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to get IdentityServer4 working inside a new .NET Core 2.1 app (it works perfectly inside a .NET Core 2.0 app).  I have tried the following:

1) Download this project, which is the IdentityServer4 application: https://github.com/ghstahl/IdentityServer4-Asp.Net-2.1-Identity-Examples/tree/e0aeeff7e078aa082c8e16029dd2c220acc77d7b

2) Download this project, which is the MVC application using the Identity Server4 application: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/MvcClient.

3) Add the two projects to the same solution.  The MVC project uses the IdentityServer project for authentication; authorisation etc.

I had to make the following changes:

1) Change to the Startup contained in the IdentityServer app (AddIdentityServer now accepts an argument):

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
})
```

2) Configure the IdentityServer app to listen on port 5000 and disable SSL on the identity server.

Everything works as expected out of the box, except the logout facility.  When I click log out in the MVC application; the following code is called inside the MVC app:

```
public async Task Logout() 
{ 
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies"); 
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc"); 
}
```

The user is then redirected to Logout.cshtml in the IdentityServer app.  However, they have to click log out again (on the IdentityServer app) in order to actually log out i.e. they click log out in the MVC app (point two), then log out in IdentityServer (point one).

Why does the end user have to log out twice?

Comment: Have not used it, but there is an overload of `SignOutAsync` that [does not require the schema parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: @bradbury9, could you elaborate? All the SignOutAsync constructors in that link accept at least one argument.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, they are extension methods so its first argument is the `HttpContext` object. I refer to [this overload](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions_SignOutAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_) That could be called either `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SignOutAsync(HttpContext);` o `HttpContext.SignOutAsync();` The 1st one calls directly the static method and the 2nd one uses the extension method directly.

Comment: In this scenario, you are logged in twice: Once in the MVC app and once in the IS4 app itself. When you hit `Logout` in your MVC app, you logout of the MVC app but are still logged in with IS4. This is kinda like signing into an app using Google - you're signed in to Google itself *and* the app that uses Google. When you signed out of said app that uses Google, you don't also sign out of Google itself.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, I don't believe this is the case because: 1) I can still access the secure areas of the MVC application after I have logged out and 2) With .NET Core 2.0 the user is logged out in both places.

Comment: For point 1, this is because when you hit the secure areas in the MVC app, it realises you're not signed in anymore and sends you back over to the IS4 app. You *are* signed in here so it just sends you straight back with a new token and as such you're logged in again.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, thanks for clarifying. How do I ensure the user is logged out at both ends (like when Identity Server is a .NET Core 2.0 app).  Is this possible?

Comment: As a general hint: Open your browser’s dev tools and look at the network tab. There you can see where the browser is actually going to, so you could easily see when it redirects back to the identity server for example. You can also see the HTTP response headers there, so you can inspect when cookies are set or cleared. – That’s usually very useful when debugging authentication flow related problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Account/Logout` page, which lives under `Areas/Identity/Account/Logout.cshtml.cs` in your scaffolded ASP.NET Core Identity code, there is an `OnGet` handler that looks like this:

```
public void OnGet() { }
```

Because this is using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, all this does is render the corresponding `Logout.cshtml` page. In your example, when you hit `Logout` in the MVC app, it clears its own cookies and then passes you over to the IS4 app (the `OnGet`, specifically). Because this `OnGet` handler is empty, it's not really doing anything and it's certainly not signing you out of the IS4 app.

If you look at the `OnPost` handler inside of `Logout.cshtml.cs`, you'll see it looks something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    // ...
}
```

This call to `SignOutAsync` does exactly what it suggests: it signs you out of IS4 itself. However, in your current workflow, this `OnPost` handler is not being called. The `OnGet` handler is called indirectly when you use `Logout` in the MVC app, as I've already mentioned.

Now, if you look at the controller/action implementation of IS4 logout in the [Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L175) project, you'll see that essentially it passes the `GET` request over to the `POST` request. Here's the code, with comments stripped out:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string logoutId)
{
    var vm = await BuildLogoutViewModelAsync(logoutId);

    if (vm.ShowLogoutPrompt == false)
        return await Logout(vm);

    return View(vm);
}
```

When logging out, there's a setting that controls whether or not the user should first be prompted to confirm whether or not they want to log out. That's mostly what this code is taking care of - it passes it straight over to the `POST` request handler if the prompt is not required. Here's a snippet of the code for the `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
{
    var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

    if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    return View("LoggedOut", vm);
}
```

The important line here is the call to `HttpContext.SignOutAsync` - this ends up removing the cookie that IS4 is using to keep you signed in. Once this has been removed, you're signed out of IS4. Ultimately, this is what is missing from your current implementation.

At the simplest level, you can fix your issue by updating your `OnGet` to look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();          
        return RedirectToPage(); // A redirect ensures that the cookies has gone.
    }

    return Page();
}
```

This doesn't support the `ShowLogoutPrompt` option I've detailed above, simply just to keep this answer a little bit shorter. Apart from that, it's just using `_signInManager` to do the logout given that you're in the ASP.NET Core Identity world.

I encourage you to explore the full source-code from the [Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L175) implementation in order to support `ShowLogoutPrompt`, `returnUrl`, etc - I can't possibly do that here without writing a book.

Comment: Thanks.  That does work +1.  Can I redirect to the MVC app after signing out (instead of displaying the logout page).  I can't remember how to do this - too much web forms work recently.  +1.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You'll need to set up a `PostLogoutRedirectUri` in the IS4 configuration of your MVC app. Once you've got that, look at [this code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L313) that shows how you can get the logout context and then the `PostLogoutRedirectUri` value. Actually, it looks like the other answer here has given you the code for that specifically.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to modify the code like this? What if I wanted to upgrade ASP.NET Identity in the future? I guess I would have to make all the modifications again?

Comment: It’s not a bad idea - it’s pretty much your only option. ASP.NET Core Identity is scaffolded, meaning it’s something to get you started that you can customise as needed. You can’t both customise and seamlessly upgrade at the same time. On the plus side here, logout is unlikely to go through any major changes in the near future.

Comment: @KirkLarkin seems you've forgotten to remind TS about Single Sign Out facility. It should be kept in mind at least, when considering direct jumping to PostLogout Uri.

Comment: @d_f Yep, that's a fair point. I deliberately kept things simple as the answer was already getting long. It's good for the OP to be aware of this though - it is covered in the QuickStart.UI project I referenced. Thanks for pointing this out specifically - it's an important feature of IS4 for sure. (Aside: What's TS stand for?).

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, I have asked another identity server question here if you are interested in answering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381243/can-only-authenticate-in-memory-users-from-code

Answer (score 2):

Simple logout functionalty is possible like following:

```
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LogoutModel> _logger;
        private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;
        public LogoutModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LogoutModel> logger,
            IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _interaction = interaction;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string logoutId)
        {
            return await OnPost(logoutId);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string logoutId)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
            var r = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
            if (r.PostLogoutRedirectUri == null)
            {
                return Redirect("/");
            }
            return Redirect(r.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
        }
```

Comment: One restriction when jumping to `PostLogoutRedirectUri` is Single Sign out. Great if you don't need it at all. Otherwise you have to display `LoggedOut` view to render IFrames calling signout endpoints at all the clients involved. Our solution was to firstly display `LoggedOut` view and later redirect to `PostLogoutRedirectUri` using JS and a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and **I solved it** for me and decided to put my answer here for others to see.

**Solution:** Inside IdentityServer4 Quick start project logic is already there and ready to configure it for user needs.

1. Open SolutionName/Quickstart/Account/AccountOptions.cs
2. Set **ShowLogoutPrompt** to false
3. Set **AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut** to true

[image: Example]

I hope this will help, good luck.