# Can only authenticate in memory users from code

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Please see the code below, which I took [from here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords/src/ResourceOwnerClient/Program.cs):

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5000");
if (disco.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
    return;
}

// request token
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = "ro.client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    UserName = "alice",
    Password = "password",
    Scope = "api"
});

if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
    return;
}
```

The code works as expected i.e. I can login as Alice.  Now I have replaced the IdentityServer project with my current identity server project (which uses ASP.NET Identity) and I receive an error i.e. tokenResponse.Error returns Internal Server Error.  Now, if I go into the startup file of my identity server project and comment out the line below:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
                //.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Then it works as expected (it authenticates the in memory user).  Why won't it authenticate ASP.NET Identity users?

Comment: That ISE you mention should show more information in the logs, etc. The best thing to do is try and find out what you can from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

As you see, if you want to authenticate user with AspNetIdentity, this line`.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()` isn't enough for the integration. You must register some extra services too. Also you need to update your AccountController etc.

You can check this [link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity) for AspNetIdentity integration with IdentityServer 4.

Comment: I downloaded the sample identity server app so it has the accouncontroller code etc and authentication works over the web link.  It is only the resource owner using asp.net that does not work.  Do you know a code sample that has resource owner with Sp.net identity? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but if web authentication works, resource owner auth need to work also. Ohh, you need to check Client Flow! If it's working with Implicit, Hybrid etc. flow, you need to change it with ResourceOwner flow. If you're get same error again, can you send me logs?

Comment: @w0051977 is there any change? Do you still get error?

Comment: I reinstalled Identity server (via Nuget) and upgraded all my other packages.  Then everything worked as expected.  I will mark this answer as accepted because of the hyperlink provided, which helped.  Thanks.